# ¿Cómo corto una cadena en distintos bloques del mismo tamaño?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, lista

Estoy necesitando poder tener una lista donde cada posición es una cadena de caracteres

Hasta ahora a partir de un texto pude guardar en cada posicion de la lista 5 caracteres.

Ahora necesito realizar lo siguiente:

En la primera posición de la lista se guardan los primeros 5 caracteres, a partir de la segunda posicion los caracteres no seran los 5 siguientes, sino que los ultimos dos caracteres de la primera posicion mas los siguientes 3 caracteres (para un total de cinco), se guardaran en la segunda posicion, para la tercera poscion de la lista se guardan los ultimos dos de la segunda posicion, mas los 3 seguientes y así hasta acabar con todo texto.

Ejemplo:

```
texto = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'

lista = ['abcde','defgh','ghijk','jklmn','mnñop','opqrs','rstuv','uvwxy','xyz']
```

lo que tengo hasta ahora es :

```
texto = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'
lista=[]
c=0
cad = ""
for i in texto: 
    cad=cad + i 
    c = c + 1
    if(c == 5):
        lista.append(cad)
        cad = cad[c-2:]
        c = 0   
lista.append(cad)
print(lista)
```

out

```
['abcde', 'defghij', 'ghijklmnñ', 'jklmnñopqrs', 'mnñopqrstuvwx', 'opqrstuvwxyz']
```

como ven no hace exactamente lo que necesito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que validar que la longitud de la cedana, que ya cuente con los cinco caracteres, y para la parte de la subcadena tómalos desde la posición 3 hasta la 5, creo que con eso funciona.

```
texto = 'abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz'
lista=[]
c=0
cad = ""
for i in texto: 
    cad=cad + i 
    c = c + 1
    if(c == 5 or len(cad) == 5):
        lista.append(cad)
        cad = cad[3:5]
        c = 0   
lista.append(cad)
print(lista)
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias amigo

Answer (score 3):

En el fondo, si te das cuenta, cada nueva "subcadena" de las que quieres formar comienza en una letra que ocupa una posición múltiplo de 3 en la cadena de entrada. Fíjate, el resultado esperado es:

```
['abcde','defgh','ghijk','jklmn','mnñop','opqrs','rstuv','uvwxy','xyz']
```

Y la primera letra en cada una de estas es a, d, g, j, m, o, ... Estas letras están separadas 3 unidades en la cadena original.

Por tanto basta ir tomando *slices* de la cadena original que comiencen en posiciones múltiplo de 3, y terminen 5 caracteres más allá.  No necesitamos ninguna precaución especial para el último grupo (aunque tiene menos de 5 caracteres) porque si intentas un *slice* que termine más allá del final, simplemente lo "truncará" sin dar errores.

Así pues la siguiente *comprensión de listas* haría lo que buscas:

```
resultado = [ texto[i:i+5] for i in range(0,len(texto),3) ]
```

**Nota** Si no conoces la sintaxis de *comprensiones de listas* o no se te permite usarla, en realidad es equivalente al siguiente bucle explícito:

```
resultado = []
for i in range(0,len(texto),3):
   resultado.append(texto[i:i+5])
```

Comment: gracias amigo me sirvió tu ayuda